# Problem in reading accelerometer axis (ATMEGA328P + ADXL345)

Tags: avr, atmega, accelerometer

I really need help with my project. I'm trying to connect ADXL345 with ATMEGA328P through SPI interface to send received data from Atmega328P to PC via UART interface.

The ATMEGA328P is sending the accelerometer readings over USB serial, which I am displaying on a serial terminal program. However, I couldn't display any accelerometer readings on the terminal. I'm not sure where I did wrong.

This is my first time writing my own program and I really hope anyone can help me solve the problem.

Connections:

```
ADXL345                 ATMEGA328P
GND---------------------GND
VCC---------------------5V
CS----------------------SS (PB2)
SDO---------------------MISO(PB4)
SDA---------------------MOSI(PB3)
SCL---------------------SCK(PB5)
```

[Datasheet for ATMEGA328P](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf)

[Datasheet for ADXL345](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADXL345.pdf)

```
/*******************************************************
Chip type               : ATmega328P
Program type            : Application
AVR Core Clock frequency: 16.000000 MHz
Memory model            : Small
External RAM size       : 0
Data Stack size         : 512
*******************************************************/

//#include <io.h>
#include <mega328p.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <spi.h>
#include <delay.h>
#include <math.h>

//Register addresses for ADXL345

#define RANGE_16G           0x0B
#define MEASURE             0x08
#define DEVID               0x00 // Device ID
#define THRESH_TAP          0x1D // Tap threshold
#define OFSX                0x1E // X-axis offset
#define OFSY                0x1F // Y-axis offset
#define OFSZ                0x20 // Z-axis offset
#define DUR                 0x21 // Tap duration
#define LATENT              0x22 // Tap latency
#define WINDOW              0x23 // Tap window
#define THRESH_ACT          0x24 // Activity threshold
#define THRESH_INACT        0x25 // Inactivity threshold
#define TIME_INACT          0x26 // Inactivity time
#define ACT_INACT_CTL       0x27 // Axis enable control for activity and inactivity detection
#define THRESH_FF           0x28 // Free-fall threshold
#define TIME_FF             0x29 // Free-fall time
#define TAP_AXES            0x2A // Axis control for single tap/double tap
#define ACT_TAP_STATUS      0x2B // Source of single tap/double tap
#define BW_RATE             0x2C // Data rate and power mode control
#define POWER_CTL           0x2D  //Power saving Control
#define INT_ENABLE          0x2E  // interrupt enable control
#define INT_MAP             0x2F   //interrupt mapping control
#define INT_SOURCE          0x30 //source of interrupts
#define DATA_FORMAT         0x31//Data Format
#define DATAX0              0x32 // X-Axis Data 0
#define DATAX1              0x33 // X-Axis Data 1
#define DATAY0              0x34 // Y-Axis Data 0
#define DATAY1              0x35 // Y-Axis Data 1
#define DATAZ0              0x36 // Z-Axis Data 0
#define DATAZ1              0x37 // Z-Axis Data 1
#define FIFO_CTL            0x38 //Fifo control
#define FIFO_STATUS         0x39 //Fifo status

//
// Expresed as output data rate
#define DATA_RATE_3200            0x0F
#define DATA_RATE_1600            0x0E
#define DATA_RATE_800            0x0D
#define DATA_RATE_400            0x0C
#define DATA_RATE_200            0x0B
#define DATA_RATE_100            0x0A
#define DATA_RATE_50            0x09
#define DATA_RATE_25            0x08

#define W 0x00
#define R 0x80



//Function prototypes
void ADXL345_init(char range, char data_rate);
void ADXL345_write(unsigned char addr,unsigned char data);
unsigned char ADXL345_read(unsigned char addr);
void read_accelerometer_1(void);
void spi_init(void);

// Declare your global variables here
unsigned char ADXL345_ID;
unsigned char lsb, msb;
signed int x_acc1, y_acc1, z_acc1;

void main(void)
{

    // Crystal Oscillator division factor: 2 (8MHz)
        #pragma optsize-
        CLKPR=0x80;
        CLKPR=0x01;
        #ifdef _OPTIMIZE_SIZE_
        #pragma optsize+
        #endif

    // Input/Output Ports initialization
    // SCK(PB5):Output, MISO(PB4):Input, MOSI(PB3):Output, SS(PB2):Output
    PORTB=0x04;     // 0b 0000 0100   SS set to 1
    DDRB=0x2C;      // 0b 0010 1100   SS , SCK , MOSI and as outputs      


    // USART initialization
        // Communication Parameters: 8 Data, 1 Stop, No Parity
        // USART Receiver: On
        // USART Transmitter: On
        // USART0 Mode: Asynchronous
        // USART Baud Rate: 2 Mbps (Double Speed Mode)
        UCSR0A=0x02;
        UCSR0B=0x18;
        UCSR0C=0x06;
        UBRR0H=0x00;
        UBRR0L=0x00;


    spi_init();


    ADXL345_init(RANGE_16G, DATA_RATE_100);

    while(1)
    {
        read_accelerometer_1();

      //    
      printf("%d,%d,%d", x_acc1, y_acc1, z_acc1);
      printf(",__,");    

    }

}

//spi initialization

void spi_init(void)

{

    PORTB=0x04;     
    DDRB=0x2C;

    SPCR=(0<<SPIE) | (1<<SPE) | (0<<DORD) | (1<<MSTR) | (1<<CPOL) | (1<<CPHA) | (0<<SPR1) | (0<<SPR0);
    SPSR=(0<<SPI2X);

}

//Accelerometer functions

void ADXL345_init(char range, char data_rate)
{
    ADXL345_ID=ADXL345_read(DEVID);
    printf("Device ID=%X\n\r", ADXL345_ID);
    ADXL345_write(POWER_CTL,0x00); //Standby mode
    ADXL345_write(BW_RATE, data_rate);          //Setup the device bandwidth and output data rate
    ADXL345_write(DATA_FORMAT, range);          //Setup data
    ADXL345_write(POWER_CTL, MEASURE);     //Measurement mode
    delay_ms(20);
}

void ADXL345_write(unsigned char addr,unsigned char data)   //write to the ADXL345
{
    PORTB &= ~0b00000100;       //    

    SPDR = W|addr;                //

    while (!(SPSR & 0x80));      //

    SPDR=data;                  //

    PORTB |= 0b00000100;        //   

    delay_ms(10);
}   

unsigned char ADXL345_read(unsigned char addr)
// read from the ADXL345

{
     unsigned char ans;

    PORTB &= ~0b00000100;

    SPDR = R|addr;                       
    while(!(SPSR & 0x80));              
    ans=SPDR;                                 
    PORTB |= 0b00000100;                       
    return (ans);
}

void read_accelerometer_1(void)
{
// unsigned char x_raw, y_raw, z_raw;
//sensitivity

        lsb=ADXL345_read(DATAX0);
        msb=ADXL345_read(DATAX1);  
        x_acc1=((msb<<8) | lsb);     // x_raw=((msb<<8) | lsb);

        //x_acc=x_raw/sensitivity;

        lsb=ADXL345_read(DATAY0);
        msb=ADXL345_read(DATAY1);  
        y_acc1=((msb<<8) | lsb);    // y_raw=((msb<<8) | lsb);

        //  y_acc=y_raw/sensitivity;

        lsb=ADXL345_read(DATAZ0);
        msb=ADXL345_read(DATAZ1);     
        z_acc1=((msb<<8) | lsb);    //        z_raw=((msb<<8) | lsb);

        //        z_acc=z_raw/sensitivity;      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just finished a blog post recently on ADXL345 + Arduino Uno. You could find it at

http://wei48221.blogspot.tw/2015/06/how-to-use-adxl345-triple-axis.html